# Lotus getting field from database

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I am new to lotus. I need to get some info from Lotus database with Java. I have database:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, user, pwd);
Database database = session.getDatabase(server, database);
```

I have that info:

```
 field - fldContractorCode;
 form - form="formAgreement";
```

For example field is "abcde";
So how I can get info from that database? I need to use seatch formula? Or what methods I need to use? Thanx for help.

**UPD**

Now I am using such way:

```
DocumentCollection collection = DATABASE.search("form=\"formAgreement\"");
Document doc = collection.getFirstDocument();
while(doc != null) {
   doc.getItemValueString("fldContractorCode");
   doc = collection.getNextDocument();
}
```

And it works fine for me, but I think that way is not very comfortable because to find some document for example with field="abcd"  I need to itearte over collection every time...
So that why I am asking for some way to find document by the field value. And I dont understand what is VIEW in database and where to get this VIEW name.

Comment: Make sure to recycle().

Comment: When the object is no longer needed. For example your loop above is liable to crash the client/server with an out of memory condition. Here is a good write up. http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/geek-o-terica-5-taking-out-the-garbage-java

Comment: Ok tnx and maybe you know what language is using in db.search() method ? I was reading a lot about lotus formula language but it seems not really what I need.

Comment: db.search() uses Formula language. FTSearch() uses FT syntax. Which can be notes style or web style depending on the client settings (or how you wrote your search term) .. although I am not 100% on that for code calls. Kind of a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your existing code, you can just change one line:

```
DocumentCollection collection = DATABASE.search("form=\"formAgreement\ & "fldContractorCode=\"abcd\"");
```

However, this will be slow if the database contains many documents.  For best performance, you should consider using Domino Designer to add a new view to your database and using the `getDocumentByKey()` method suggested in the other answers.  If that is not an option, Simon's suggestion of using the `FTSearch()` method is faster than the `Search()` method, but only if a full text index exists for the database.  It also has a slightly different syntax for the search string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to get the document.

1. Search for the document from a view, where the first column of the view contains a sorted value of the fldContractorCode.

For example:

```
String key = "abide";
View view = db.getView("viewName");
Document doc = view.getDocumentByKey(key, true);
```

2. You can use the Database FTSearch Method to do a full text search to find the document. You will need the database to have a full text index created.

3. If you know the UNID or notes ID of the document you can use getDocumentByUNID() or getDocumentByID().

Your question is quite broad, so I recommend reading the Infocenter as it details sample code for each method.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATABASE_CLASS_JAVA.html

Comment: Thanx anyway. And can I use in search formula something like this `form="formContractor" WHERE fldContractoCode = "abcd"` to get needed Document, not the full collections of document ? UPD. Sorry I was reading your answer inattentively!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drill down to the DOCUMENT (not Form) you want to retrieve the field from.

Lotus Notes has a very easy to understand hierarchical way to get to where you want. You will need to instantiate objects in this sequence:

```
Session
Database
View
Document
```

Let's say you have a view called $(sysAgreements) that list all forms "formAgreement".
Its selection formula would be something like this:

```
SELECT Form="formAgreement"
```

To get to the document or documents you want you will do something like this:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, user, pwd);
Database database = session.getDatabase(server, database);
View view = database.getView("$(sysAgreements)");
Document doc = view.getDocumentByKey(VIEW_KEY);
String fieldContent = doc.getItemValueString("fldContractorCode");
```

There are several ways to retrieve info from a Notes database. This is one of them. Bear in mind that they key used by Notes to search a view with getDocumentByKey is the 1st sorted column.

If you want to get multiple documents you can use:

```
DocumentCollection docCol = view.getAllDocumentsByKey(VIEW_KEY);
```

and then iterate over it.

Avoid doing ftsearch because it's slow and a bit painful to Notes. Prefere looking up in the views.

Also another powerful source of help is the Notes help. Get the help database from a computer that has the Notes Development Client installed. But pay attention to the name of the help you're picking, there are 3 helps in Notes: the client, development and administration. Development is what you want.